# Android textAllCaps in Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have a theme where on wanted all textviews on activities to be capitalized.  So I set textAllCaps in a style and then applied it to textViewStyle in my theme like the below

```
<style name="Widget.Apex.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Widget.Apex.TextView</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately this had the side effect of turning my Application Title, ActionBar subtitles, and popmenu items capitalized.  So I thought I would just set the ActionBarStyle, textAppearanceLargePopupMenu, and textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu attributes in my theme to have a custom style with textAllCaps=false.  However, this does not work.  I know my themes are being applied because if I set textColor or textStyle they are both applied to the titles and menu items.  Is it possible to override the textAllCaps in these styles?

```
<style name="Widget.Apex.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Apex.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
  <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Apex.ActionBar</item>
  <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
  <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.Apex.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>
  <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Widget.Apex.TextView</item>
</style>
```

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: Are you trying to make a specific `TextView` all caps? If not, then would you mind telling everyone what it is you're trying to make all caps? It may not be necessary to set your style as is.

Comment: Sure.  I'm trying to make all TextViews that appear on Activities all caps.  However, the side effect is that there are a couple of places that use TextViews that are getting the all caps style, so I want to undo the all caps in those particular places.  The two places that I currently know of are the titles and the menu popups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using **AppCompat** `textAllCaps` in Android Apps supporting older API's (less than 14)

A work around for this would to explicitly set the style like this:

```
<android.support.v7.internal.widget.CompatTextView
        style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:textAllCaps="true"/>
```

or alternatively use a new style that inherits textViewStyle and adds the textAllCaps attribute along with any other styles of your choosing:

```
  <style name="MyCompatTextViewStyle" parent="MyTextViewStyle">
            <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
        </style>
```

*In layout:*

```
<android.support.v7.internal.widget.CompatTextView
            style="@style/MyCompatTextViewStyle"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Note:

1> this widget won't inherit any default styles that are set in your theme via `android:textViewStyle`

2>Using this widget seems to be internal given the package name meaning it's not really intended for public API. It's also not "fully baked" in that the `textAllCaps` attribute needs to be directly on the style/view and can not be in the textAppearance style for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with both `textAllCaps` and `android:textAllCaps`.

```
<style name="TextViewStyle">
      <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
      <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

But I think it's working just with design library 23.2.0 or later.