# textAllCaps not working below api 14 in AppcompatButton

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton which states
[Supports textAllCaps style attribute which works back to Eclair MR1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html)
but i tested in emulator with api 10 with `android:textAllCaps = "false"`, its not working.
Any  comments or why the doc is stating wrong or what am i doing wrong?

It doesn't work with app prefix either.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html

Supports `textAllCaps` style attribute which works back to [`Eclair MR1`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#ECLAIR_MR1) (***Android 2.1-Added in API level 7***).

Check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470083/4409113

```
<android.support.v7.internal.widget.CompatTextView
        style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:textAllCaps="true"/>
```

Use it with `app` prefix.

Comment: . why do i have to make a style for that?

Comment: it doesn't work with app prefix if we don't use style attribute,why?