# textAllCaps converts to wrong latter in localization manner

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I think there is a bug in textAllCaps, converting small letter to wrong capital letter. In Turkish language, small letter 'i' must be convert to capital letter 'İ'. But Android converts it to capital letter 'I'.

TextView is like below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="istanbul"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

I expect to see 'İSTANBUL', but Android converts it to 'ISTANBUL'

Anybody else has faced this issue before?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215326/android-textallcaps-in-theme

Comment: Are You sure that 'android:text="istanbul"' typed in Turkish locale? If "i" in "istanbul" typed as English letter it anyway converts to "I".

Comment: And take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase) question.

Comment: My keyboard settings are Turkish localized. I am using a Turkish keyboard. My project encoding is UTF-8